# Getting phone number and showing warning using Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to make a program which is getting a phone number and if it has alphabet letters then showing a warning message.
Phone number has to be in following type.

**423-243-789**

If input is like following type, then program needs to show warning message and ask entering numbers again.

**121-34n**

So basically I need to use Loop but I'm not used to using Loop in Assembly Language.
Here's my code I wrote so far.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data 
   str1 BYTE "Enter your number", 0
   str2 BYTE "Only digits available. Please Enter again", 0
   input BYTE 50 DUP(?)
   
.code
main PROC
   
   mov edx, 0
   mov edx, offset str1
   call WriteString
   call Crlf

   L1:
      mov edx, offset input
      mov ecx, SIZEOF input - 1
      call ReadString
      
      ......??......

      mov edx, offset str2
      call WriteString
      call Crlf
    loop L1

   exit

main ENDP
END main
```

I can't solve how to check if the input is available or not(including letters). NEED YOUR HELP!!!

Comment: The `loop` instruction is a special purpose operation for counting down `ecx`. Your loop has a condition different than countint down a certain amount of iterations. So you shouldn't use the `loop` instruction but a simple `jmp` instead.

Comment: `call ReadString` should tell you how many character were read. Let ESI point at `input` and EDI at `input+read_size`.  While ESI<EDI  keep loading AL from [ESI], increment ESI, check if AL is valid and warn when not. You can compare ESI to `input+3` and to `input+7` to find out if AL should be '-' or a digit between '0' and '9'.